# Java REST API: POST Method gets NULL parameters

Tags: java, android, rest, google-app-engine, httpclient

I'm sending parameters from my android app to the backend and trying to retrieve the parameters sent by my android clients in my POST Method but I keep getting null parameters even though the clients are sending parameters which are not null.

**Java POST Method:**

```
@POST
@Produces({ "application/json" })
@Path("/login")
public LoginResponse Login(@FormParam("email") String email, @FormParam("password") String password) {
    LoginResponse response = new LoginResponse();

    if(email != null && password != null && email.length() != 0 && password.length() != 0){
        //Detect if null or empty
        //Code
    }

    return response;
}
```

**Android Client:**

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://MY_APP_NAME.appspot.com/user/login");

String json = "";
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

try {
    jsonObject.accumulate("email", "roger@gmail.com");
    jsonObject.accumulate("password", "123");

    json = jsonObject.toString();

    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
    httppost.setEntity(se);
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httppost.setHeader("ACCEPT", "application/json");
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
}
catch(Exception ex) { }
```

I believe the Content-Type of the method and the client is the same as well. Why am I not receiving the parameters from the Java Backend Method?

**CHECKED:**

- The URL is correct and the connection is working
- The Parameters sent by the app are not null

Comment: Did check `LoginResponse`  in you Java client ? 
Use [Post man](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) and pass your parameters to same url with post type, let us know what your getting? 
I think in the back end your not return any thing

Comment: I am returning data and it works well in postman when I send the body data as x-www-form-urlencoded. No idea why. I didnt include that in the question since it was irrelevant. Edited it in anyway. The problem is that I am getting null parameters in the backend method @Kathi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We hope i got you, try `NameValuePair`

```
public void postData() {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/yourscript.php");

    try {

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "123"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("string", "Hey"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // Catch Protocol Exception
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Catch IOException
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you have similar problems, I'd suggest using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)
which is a free http inspector and debugger by which you can see the http request your app is sending to the backend server and the backend answer.

Best of luck